# Calculating Expectation and Covariance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X$ is a random variable which is uniformly distributed on the interval $[1,4]$. Define the random variable $Y = g(x)$ with $g(x) = x^2$

How can I calculate $E(g(X))$, $g(E(X))$ and the covariance Cov$[X,Y]$?

I would really appreciate it if someone can show me how to solve this !

Comment: $g(E(X))$ should be the easiest, can you get that?

Answer (score 2):

The probability density function of $X$ is defined as

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}\frac13 & 1\le x\le 4\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The expectation of $Y$, $E[Y] = E[g(X)]$ can be obtained by
$$\begin{align*}E[g(X)] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\ f_X(x)\ dx\\
&= \int_1^4x^2\cdot\frac13\ dx\\
&= \frac13\int_1^4x^2\ dx\\
&= \frac13\left[\frac{x^3}3\right]_1^4\\
&= 7
\end{align*}$$

---

By symmetry of uniform distribution, $E[X]$ can be quickly calculated as
$$E[X] = \frac{4+1}2 = 2.5,$$
or not as quickly calculated by
$$E[X] = \int_1^4x\cdot\frac13\ dx = \frac13\left[\frac{x^2}2\right]_1^4 = 2.5.$$
Then $g(E[X]) = 2.5^2$.

---

The covariance $COV(X,Y) = E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]$,
$$\begin{align*}COV(X,Y) &= E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]\\
&= E[XY] - E[X]\cdot E[Y]\\
&= \frac13\int_1^4 x^3\ dx - 2.5\cdot 7\\
&= \frac13\left[\frac{x^4}4\right]_1^4 - 2.5\cdot 7\\
&= 3.75
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Can you explain why $E(g(X)) > g(E(X))$ in this problem?

Comment: (Informally) this is due to the convexity of $g(x) = x^2$. To roughly see the effect, notice that the mean of $X = 2.5$ maps to $6.25$, the high-end $X=4$ maps to $16$, and the low-end $X=1$ maps to $1$. And the mean of $16$ and $1$ is larger than $6.25$.

Comment: And coincidentally, in this question $g(x) = x^2$. Recall that $$VAR[X] = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2 = E[g(X)] - g(E[X]),$$ and variance is always non-negative and is zero only when $X$ only takes one value.

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

**Hints**

You need
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]\\
g(\mathbb{E}[X]) = \mathbb{E}[X] \times \mathbb{E}[g(X)] \\
\textrm{Cov}(X,Y)
$$
can you get the first two?